# Cannot route to controller when using ngMaterial

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, angular-material

I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- HomeController <- HomeController.
```

With my code. Which says that my dependency is probably not defined or spelled correctly. But I believe it is something else, that I don't understand!? So can someone please help me. I'm trying to learn Angular Material. I have done routing in this way before and it works If I'm not go with Material. So why does Material mess things up?

This is what I have done so far:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app=ubeachPage>

<head>
  <title>UBeach</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
  <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/styles.css">

  <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="controllers\RegisterController.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers\HomeController.js"></script>
  <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
  <main ng-view></main>
</body>

</html>
```

**client.js:**

```
var ubeachPage = angular.module('ubeachPage', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngAria']);

ubeachPage.config(['$routeProvider', '$mdThemingProvider', function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {

$mdThemingProvider.theme('altTheme')
    .primaryPalette('green')

$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('purple', {
        'default': '500',
        'hue-1': '100',
        'hue-2': '600',
        'hue-3': 'A100'
    })
    .accentPalette('green', {
        'default': '200'
    })
    .dark();

$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
    })
    .when('/result', {
        templateUrl: 'views/result.html'
        //      controller: 'ResultController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

I use a header.html file for the toolbar with page buttons.

**header.html:**

```
<md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings" ng-disabled="false">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>

    <h2 flex md-truncate>UBeach</h2>

    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#!/home" name="page1">Home</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#!/register" name="page3">Register</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#!/result" name="page2">Scoreboard</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg" style="color: greenyellow;"></md-icon>
    </md-button>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

**HomeController:**

```
angular.module('ubeachPage').controller('HomeController', [
  '$scope',

  function($scope) {


  }
]);
```

Comment: I had use camecase for the controller names. That dident work with angular. *If someone else happens to end up at this question and have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Mine is almost the same but works fine for me, the only difference I see is that you are using a "!" in your href, for the rest it looks fine to me...